# Database error deploying asp.net application on windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, deployment, windows-server-2012

I am trying to deploy an asp.net application with Enitity Framework on windows-server 2012. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on the server. When I run the application in Visual Studio it works just fine, it creates a localDB using the Entity-Framework Code First by the string in the constructor of AppDbContext.

I copied the solution to C:/inetputb/wwwroot and used the Internet Information Services Manager to create a new website where I set the Presentation Layer of my solution as the physical path.

When I start browsing the page I get this error:

```
       Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local
Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the
Windows Application event log for error details.
) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name
is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error
occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application
event log for error details.
)

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be
identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 



[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error
occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network
Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an
automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object
providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean
redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData
reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
applyTransientFaultHandling) +1394
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool
pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1120
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey
poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
oldConnection) +964
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
oldConnection) +114
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate,
Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&
connection) +1631
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
connection) +267
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,
DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
retry) +211
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
+393
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing,
Action`3 executed) +104
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +442
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
+562
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +16
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
operation) +229
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +916
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +111
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +203
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
connection) +129
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +172
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +110
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +118
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
+284
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
context) +185
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
+72
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
+502
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
action) +273
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
entityType) +38
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +56
System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +61
BL.Facades.StatisticsFacade.GetDistributionData(String factorFamiliarName,
Int32 versionID) +1396
PL.Controllers.StatisticsController.Index() in C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyFirstProject\MyFirstProject\PL\Controllers\StatisticsController.cs:19
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +209
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
+35
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +67
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +30
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +186
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +65
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +65
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
completedSynchronously) +137
```

I am trying to deploy this project unsuccessfuly for weeks and really need to get it done. Can someone please tell me what to I do wrong?
Before this I tried do deploy it using sql server express 2014 without visual studio intalled, still couldn't make it work..

Comment: Visual Studio runs everything via your user account with your permissions. IIS runs with a different user account that has it's own set of permissions. You need to make sure your IIS application user has permissions to do all of the things your web wants to do.

Comment: I changed LocalDB for SQL Server Express 2014 and was getting the same exception. Then I used this solution for granting permissions. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/#OurIIS

Answer (score 0):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.......

this error says, your connection details to the database is not correct.
refer: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/